# How to include time in the date column of an export from the WordPress WP All Export Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am using WP All Export Plugin to export posts but I can't get it to export the Time part of the post date. My date column in the exported CSV file only contains the date. I have tried the following:

Changing the date format in Settings to `d-m-Y H:i` and exported but only the date part of the post is exported. How can I go about this? Feeling stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed my CSV file was not formatted properly to accommodate the date and time